# Criar Vhosts Apache no Windows: Não passa do htdocs

Tags: apache

Estou seguindo um **tutorial** na net ensinando a criar **VirtualHosts** no Apache em ambiente Windows

Meu **http-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
#ServerName www.example.com:80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fielcard.net.br
    DocumentRoot "D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\fielcard.net.br"
    ErrorLog "logs/projeto-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/projeto-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\fielcard.net.br" >
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Tem mais coisas. Porém com linhas comentadas.

Meu **hosts** do **windows**

```
127.0.0.1 fielcard.net.br
```

**Novamente**: Tem mais coisas. Porém com linhas comentadas.

**Apache 2.4
PHP 7.3**

Tentativas:

```
ServerName fielcard.net.br.local
127.0.0.1  fielcard.net.br.local
```

**Reiniciei o Apache.
Reiniciei o Windows.**

Meu Apache tem a pasta **htdocs** com um arquivo **index.php** com apenas a palava **localhost**. E dentro dela para cada site que desenvolvo existe uma pasta com o nome do site.

Então, desejo criar um **vhosts** para cada site.

O **resultado** que estou obtendo,sempre é o mesmo:

Aparece

**Localhost**

no **Browser**!

Isto é, nunca entra na pasta do projeto!

O que está **errado**?

**COMPLEMENTO**:

Descobri o seguinte:

Na pasta **conf** do **Apache** tem a pasta **extra**

Dentro dessa pasta tem 2 arquivos de configuração a saber:

```
httpd-ahssl.conf  => Configuração de Virtuais Hosts com SSL

e

httpd-vhosts.conf  => Configuração de Virtuais Hosts sem SSL
```

De fato, ao configurar o **Virtual Host** para um **site**, estava toda hora redirecionando para a página na *raiz* do **htdocs** e não para dentro do **site**.

Isso se deve pelo fato de que na pasta do **fielcard.net.br**, tem um **.htaccess** redirecionando toda entrada http para https e, como as entradas https estavam setadas seu **DocumentRoot** para a *raiz* do **localhost** logo toda tentativa de **VirtualHost** caia na raiz e por conseguinte no **index.php** que contem apenas a palavra **Localhost** como já informado anteriormente aqui na pergunta.

Sem **SSL**, a porta e sempre a **80**, logo, estava funcionando a **virtualização** mas o redirecionamento ás pastas de cada novo **host** não!

A dúvida agora passa a ser outra.

Eis o novo arquivo **httpd-ahssl.conf**

```
##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName localhost:443
  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.key"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Trabalhos/host/htdocs/fielcard.net.br"
# DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
# DocumentRoot access handled globally in httpd.conf
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName serverone.tld:443
  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/serverone.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/serverone.key"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Trabalhos/host/htdocs/fielcard.net.br"
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName servertwo.tld:443
  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/servertwo.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/servertwo.key"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Trabalhos/host/htdocs/fielcard.net.br"
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualhost> 


<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName localhost:443
  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.key"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Trabalhos/host/htdocs/mvc_crud_pdo"
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName serverone.tld:443
  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/serverone.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/serverone.key"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Trabalhos/host/htdocs/mvc_crud_pdo"
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName servertwo.tld:443
  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/servertwo.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/servertwo.key"
  DocumentRoot "D:/Trabalhos/host/htdocs/mvc_crud_pdo"
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
        Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualhost> 

# End SNI Demonstration Config
```

Não sei se estou fazendo corretamente. Mas quando digito no browser:

```
https://fielcard.net.br
```

Vai de boa.

Mas quando digito

```
https://mvc_crud_pdo
```

está abrindo

```
https://fielcard.net.br
```

ao invés de

```
https://mvc_crud_pdo
```

O que está errado agora?

Outra dúvida: se esse é mesmo caminho certo, então quer dizer que para cada virtual host terei que configurar 3 blocos de código iguais esse? Se sim, daqui um tempo esse arquivo vai estar gigante!

É assim mesmo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fielcard.net.br
    ServerAlias fielcard.net.br
    DocumentRoot "D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\fielcard.net.br"
    ErrorLog "logs/projeto-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/projeto-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\fielcard.net.br" >
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Aparece apenas uma pagina (quase) em branco com apenas a palavra localhost que é a página index.php que criei na raiz do htdocs do novo diretório de pastas do Apache

Comment: Confere se a linha que carrega o módulo não está comentada. Ela inicia com "LoadModule vhost_alias_module". Lembre de reiniciar o serviço após alterações.

Comment: tá comentada não Leonardo. Foi a primeira coisa que fiz. E sim. Reiniciei não apenas o Apache mas o Windows também!